# Filter an object that has multiple related objects in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-database-functions

Let's say I have two models that have one-to-many relationships as the code below.
I'd like to only get order objects that have more than one shipment object.

The only way I can think of is getting it through a list comprehension `[order for order in Order.objects.all() if order.shipments.count() > 1]` but it seems too inefficient.

Is there a better way of doing this query in Django?

```
class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    store = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Shipment(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='shipments')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should do it:

you can access shipments via the related name:

```
Order.objects.annotate(num_shipments=Count('shipments')).filter(num_shipments__gt=1)
```

Comment: Perfect. This works perfectly and is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!